# If.. Then in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to change the font size of a text depending on the current font size.

Algorithm:
    On clicking the text,
    If `font size = 35`, change it  to 12
    else if `font size = 12`, change it to 35

---

```js
<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</p>

<script>
   function myFunction() {
      if (document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='35px') {
        document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='12px'
      } else if(document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='12px') {
        document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='35x'
      }
   }
</script>
```

---

It changed it 12, but never changes back to 35. What did I miss here?

Comment: injavascript (and many other languages) `=` is assignment, what you are looking for is  `==` (or even `===` in javascript) to test for equality

Comment: okay but why are there so many downvotes in my question lol

Comment: @Subaz: Probably because it is expected that you read some basic JavaScript tutorial (where this would be covered). http://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html#h_5G7gD95A6V

Comment: dunno ... perhaps because this question has been asked so many times - though, to be fair, it's hard to search for something you don't know about :p

Comment: I've been doing VB.NET for so long i didn't expect `=` and `==` coming on the way. Just got started with `Javascript`. I was trying this code with w3school and it didn't work and I had no idea why it didn't work.. i looked up if then but the difference in = and == didn't even come in my mind haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assignment in the `if` statement. You need to use not `=`, but `==` or better `===`.

**Also one note**, if the `font-size` is defined in the `css`, it may return to you an empty string for the first time. In this case you need to use [**window.getComputedStyle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the `font-size`.

```js
function myFunction() {
      const element = document.getElementById('demo');
      console.log(element.style.fontSize);
      const fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');

      if (fontSize === '35px') {
        element.style.fontSize = '12px';
      } else if(fontSize === '12px') {
        element.style.fontSize = '35px';
      }
}
```

```css
p#demo {
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `=` in `if statement` like `if(a=b)`. When this code will run `javascript engine` will assign `b` to `a`. And that's why it will always execute the same code inside the `if(a=b)` block.  That's how, this would be translated in machine language. If you want a comparison b/w `a and b`, you should use `a==b` or `a===b`. This will make the required block to get executed bases on the condition specified.

Answer (score 0):

you are using '=' instead of '==' and another important thing - you should store fontsize in a variable and then do the comparision.

The optimized code will be -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

    <p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var element= document.getElementById('demo'),
          fontSize=element.style.fontSize;

      if (fontSize === '35px') {
       element.style.fontSize='12px'
      } else if(fontSize ==='12px') {
        element.style.fontSize='35x'
      }

    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparison of font size you are assigning size.

```
document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='35px'
```

You should change it to following :

```
document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize=='35px'
```

Same For both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Three Mistakes from your end. First one is you don't have any `style` tag in your html mark-up. Second one is conditional operator `==` you entered as `=`. Last mistake is typo `35x` should be `35px` in the second condition like below.

```
<p id="demo" style="font-size:35px;" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</p>

if (document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize=='35px') {
    document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='12px';
  } else if(document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize=='12px') {
    document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='35px';
  }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/n4wv13v1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This :
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

    <p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {

    var el = document.getElementById('demo');
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
      if (fontSize==16) {
        document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='12px';
      } else if(fontSize==12) {
        document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='35px';
      }

    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is exactly what Suren Srapyan has said, but here is the correct code:

```js
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

    <p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      if (document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize === '35px') {
        document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='12px'
      } else if(document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize ==='12px') {
        document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='35x'
      }

    }
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And by the way make a variable and store the element so you dont have to enter it EVERY time: `var demo = document.getElementById("demo");` and use `demo` for anything. Hope this helps :P

Comment: The above code won't work. Did you tried in jsfiddle?